# ¿En qué dirección tiene lugar la operación XOR?

Tags: c, booleano

Sé que

- local_18 : 0
- local_17 : b
- local_16 : b
- local_15 : 0
- local_14 : 9
- local_13 : 5
- local_12 : 4
- local_11 : f

Tengo que predecir otras variables relacionadas dado que:

```
          fgets((char *)&local_28,0x10,stdin);
          sVar2 = strlen((char *)&local_28);
          if (sVar2 == 9) {
            if ((((((local_28 ^ local_18) == 1) && ((local_27 ^ local_17) == 0x54)) &&
                 ((local_26 ^ local_16) == 0x55)) &&
                (((local_25 ^ local_15) == 0x51 && ((local_24 ^ local_14) == 9)))) &&
               (((local_23 ^ local_13) == 7 &&
                (((local_22 ^ local_12) == 0x57 && (local_11 == local_21)))))) {
              puts("You're done !");
              most_difficult_part();
              iVar1 = 0;
            }
```

¿Cómo puedo saber en qué dirección va la operación XOR?

Hasta que 0 = 0x30, Con el primero puedo suponer que local_28 =0x31

Comment: Como asi que en que direccion?

Comment: La operación XOR te indica los bits que cambian, te da igual el sentido. La operación XOR es conmutativa